# pass value of clicked link to handler with Jquery .On()

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I am trying to get value of clicked `<a>` because my `<a>`s is dynamically insert by ajax so I'm forced to use `.on()`
And tried to get my things done with `.on()` as suggest  but struggle with the simple example and failing to pass parameter of my clicked `<a>`.

*desired output*

```
click art -> alert with hello 5
click entertainment -> alert with hello 5
```

*current code*

```
function myHandler(event) {
alert(event.data.foo+event.data.value);
}

$(document).on("click","a.suggest",{foo: "hello "}, myHandler);
```

//i tried put $this but its no working and returning the content of whole page and not the clicked

this is my html code that generated dynamically

```
<ul class="stags_btn" >
<li><a class="suggest"value="5">art</a></li>
<li><a class="suggest"value="3">entertainment</a></li>
<li><a class="suggest"value="23">supplier</a></li>
<li><a class="suggest"value="81">flyer</a></li>
<li><a class="suggest"value="32">company</a></li>
<li><a class="suggest"value="2">digital</a></li>
</ul>
```

here is my findle i am using the latest jquery (1.10.1)
http://jsfiddle.net/SvJQu/1/

Comment: `value` attribute is not supported by `a`

Comment: Also why do you want `5` to be alerted out on every click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOA  `value` attribute is not supported in `<a>` tag, you can use `alt`
 instead of value.

you can get the alt value using `attr('alt')` and

`this.text` will return whatever the text between the `<a>...</a>`

#### HTML

```
<ul class="stags_btn" >
<li><a class="suggest" alt="5" >art</a></li>
<li><a class="suggest" alt="3">entertainment</a></li>
<li><a class="suggest" alt="23">supplier</a></li>
<li><a class="suggest" alt="81">flyer</a></li>
<li><a class="suggest" alt="32">company</a></li> 
<li><a class="suggest" alt="2">digital</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### jQuery

```
function myHandler(event) {
        alert(event.data.foo);
        alert($(this).attr('alt'));
        alert(this.text);
}

$(document).on("click","a.suggest",{foo: "hello"}, myHandler);
```

[`working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/SvJQu/4/)

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, you can use `$(this)` inside your `myHandler()`

```
function myHandler(event) {
    alert(event.data.foo+$(this).attr('value'));
}

$(document).on("click","a.suggest",{foo: "hello"}, myHandler);
```

But just a sidenote: the `value` that you're trying to use is not supported by `<a>` as a standard attribute, it'll get treated as a custom attribute and custom attributes are normally prefixed with `data-`.

See this fiddle here: [Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/SvJQu/2/)

Comment: Omg you solved it ! Thanks ! , Just one more question am i doing the things right? i mean writing <a> with value ? Is there any chance that browser will ignore the value ?

Comment: You can, but you should prefix it with `data-` instead to make it more standardized.